# 'Pin To Start' custom tile

Tags: html, windows-phone-8

When a user 'Pins To Start' on their wp8 / wp8.1 phone, how can I change the image that is saved as the live tile? Can I modify this?

I am guessing there is some sort of meta-tag or something that I am not aware of.

**EDIT** Sorry, i really should have clarified, this is for when you pin to start a **web-page** and it appears in the start menu.  I was sure there was a meta tag that went into the  section that solved it.  Or is it something to do with Favicon?

Comment: http://www.kashyapas.com/2013/11/17/how-to-add-a-primary-live-tile-for-your-windows-phone-8-application/

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try this ,This is for pinning a secondary tile.I am unsure of the possibility for changing the image in primary tile

```
 StandardTileData standardTileData = new StandardTileData();


            standardTileData.BackgroundImage = new Uri("ApplicationIcon.png", UriKind.Relative);

            standardTileData.Title = "Your title";
            standardTileData.Count = 26;
            standardTileData.BackTitle = "Pinned";
            standardTileData.BackContent = "Tile";
            standardTileData.BackBackgroundImage = "Your image URL";



            ShellTile tiletopin = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NavigationUri.ToString().Contains("MainPage.xaml"));


            if (tiletopin == null)
            {
                ShellTile.Create(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative), standardTileData);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Already Pinned");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the Images on the pinned tile you need to update the images in the WMAppManifest.xml file.
Open the  WMAppManifest.xml file present in Properties in Solution Explorer:
[image]

Once you Open the file Go to Application UI Tab and update the icons for small, Medium and Large size. The Icon that comes up when you pin the Application icon is The Medium Icon. So that will come up:

[image]